# Method used alongside OnCreate() to update an activity?

Tags: java, android, android-studio, android-recyclerview

I have an android studio activity that contains a RecyclerView, Adapter, and an invisible button at the bottom of the activity. Each itemView thats inside the RecyclerView also has a CheckBox. Inside my Adapter Class I have my Checkbox initialized and has something like - if checkbox.isChecked - then make public static int num = 1 else num = 2; This static variable is then sent to my Activity_main where my bottom button that I need to become Visible can be visible using an if statement that says - if Adapter.num == 1 then button.MakeVisible(true);

Issue is that it's in my Oncreate which is only called once the activity is made. The static number is sent no problem but the activity doesn't update to actually show this. I have to restart the activity to have the button actually become visible.

**Adapter Class**

```
public static int p = 0;
 @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull final Adapter.CustomViewHolder holder, 
  final int position) {

                    addedCars = new ArrayList<>();

                    holder.car.setText(mCars.get(position).getCarName());






                    holder.mCheckBox.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onClick(View view) {
                            if(holder.mCheckBox.isChecked()){
                                Log.d("tag1", "checked");

                                addedCars.add(mCars.get(position));
                                String x = Integer.toString(addedCars.size());
                                Log.d("tag1", x );

                                p = 1;



                                holder.mButton2.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                                    @Override
                                    public void onClick(View view) {

                                    }
                                });



            }
            else {
                Log.d("tag1", "unchecked");
                addedCars.remove(mCars.get(position));

                p = 2;

            }
        }

    });



}
```

**Activity_Main Class**

```
 public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

RecyclerView mRecyclerView;
Adapter mAdapter;
RecyclerView.LayoutManager mLayoutManager;




Button mButton;


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    mRecyclerView = findViewById(R.id.RecyclerView);

    mButton = findViewById(R.id.button);





    ArrayList<Car> cars = new ArrayList<>();

    cars.add(new Car("Toyota"));
    cars.add(new Car("Ford"));
    cars.add(new Car("Tesla"));

    mAdapter = new Adapter(cars);
    mRecyclerView.setAdapter(mAdapter);
    mLayoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(this);
    mRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(mLayoutManager);
    mRecyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);



   if (mAdapter.p == 1){
       mButton.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
   }








       }


  }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to send the num p from RecyclerView Adapter to the activity you need an interface to do so following steps to be followed :

have tested my code in android hope this works for you

1. creating an interface in the adapter

   ```
       // create an instance of OnItemChangeListener 
       public OnItemChangeListener onItemChangeListener;

       public interface OnItemChangeListener {
            void onItemChanged(int p);
        }

        //set the instance of onItemChangeListener from the main activity
        public void setOnItemChangeListener(OnItemChangeListener onItemChangeListener) {
               this.onItemChangeListener = onItemChangeListener;
        }

         holder.mCheckBox.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                   @Override
                   public void onClick(View view) {
                       if(holder.mCheckBox.isChecked()){
                           Log.d("tag1", "checked");

                           addedCars.add(mCars.get(position));
                           String x = Integer.toString(addedCars.size());
                           Log.d("tag1", x );

                           p = 1;
                           /*
                            * notify updated value using call back 
                            */

                            onItemChangeListener.onItemChanged(p);



                           holder.mButton2.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                               @Override
                               public void onClick(View view) {

                               }
                           });



       }
   ```

2 finally notify update to the main activity

```
mAdapter = new Adapter(cars);

mAdapter.setOnItemChangeListener(new /*your adapter name */.OnItemChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemChanged(int p) {
            // here you will get the latest updated value of p 
            // now you can update you view accordingly
        }
});



mRecyclerView.setAdapter(mAdapter);
mLayoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(this);
mRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(mLayoutManager);
mRecyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);
```

Comment: you mean create an interface in the Adapter?

Comment: Perfect. Works flawlessly. Can I ask you why we must use an interface for this work?